# How do I find all tuples with a specific value?

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching, tuples

I am working on a list populated with tuples of the form:

```
tups = [(1, 2, 4.56), (2, 1, 1.23), (1, 3, 2.776), ...]
```

and I want to perform two operations.

The first is to find all tuples starting with the number *n*, for example:

```
def starting_with(n, tups):
    '''Find all tuples with tups that are of the form (n, _, _).'''
    # ...
```

And the second is the opposite, find all tuples with the second value of *n*:

```
def middle_with(n, tups):
    '''Find all tuples with tups that are of the form (_, n, _).'''
    # ...
```

In a sense, pattern matching on a list of tuples. How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> tups = [(1, 2, 4.56), (2, 1, 1.23), (1, 3, 2.776)]
>>> [t for t in tups if t[0] == 1] # starting_with 1
[(1, 2, 4.56), (1, 3, 2.776)]
>>> [t for t in tups if t[1] == 3] # (_, 3, _)
[(1, 3, 2.776)]
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE**: Using an object that match any number. ([`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__))

```
>>> class AnyNumber(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...     def __ne__(self, other):
...         return False
... 
>>> ANY = AnyNumber()
>>> ANY == 0
True
>>> ANY == 1
True

>>> tups = [(1, 2, 4.56), (2, 1, 1.23), (1, 3, 2.776)]
>>> [t for t in tups if t == (1, ANY, ANY)] 
[(1, 2, 4.56), (1, 3, 2.776)]
>>> [t for t in tups if t == (ANY, 1, ANY)] 
[(2, 1, 1.23)]
```

Comment: but i think the first method will be faster

Answer (score 0):

```
def starting_with(n, tups):
    '''Find all tuples with tups that are of the form (n, _, _).'''
    return [t for t in tups if t[0] == n]
```